# How do you solve $(\sum_{r=1}^{30} \frac{r^2}{r^2-30r+450}) -24$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$(\sum_{r=1}^{30} \frac{r^2}{r^2-30r+450}) -24$$

My idea was to try and create a difference between two perfect squares in the denominator and then break it using partial fractions, but that didn't work

$$(\sum_{r=1}^{30} \frac{r^2}{(r-15)^2+225}) -24$$

Since the numeric term is still positive here

Comment: What is the context? How do we know if this has a nice solution or not?

Comment: Hint: As suggested by your observation , pair up the r-th term with the (n-r)-th term. (How is this hint suggested?) (Deal with $r=15$ separately).

Comment: Thanks, got it!

Comment: I would just type it into a spreadsheet and be done.  Copy down would make it easy.  BTW you are evaluating an expression, not solving an equation.